# Custom menu in Sonata (Symfony) without creating a new entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm new to stackoverflow (it's my first post), and new to Symfony2 and SonataAdmin (a bundle) too, and I have a little problem (I searched, but I cant find a working solution..).

I've created a few entities and they all appear on the left of the dashboard, in the menu, and this is working fine.

But what I want to do is add tabs without creating entity, and when you click on this menu tab, only the content of the right to be changed ! Is that possible? Thank you

Comment: should I insert screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty template in the `Resources/views` directory of your own admin  bundle
(e.g. `custom_layout.html.twig`).

Then, in your `app/config` open `config.yml` (or `sonata/admin.yml` if you have separated config files for sonata) and add (or update if exists) the following :

```
sonata_admin:
    # ...
    templates:
        layout: YourBundle::custom_layout.html.twig
```

Last, open the empty template, make it extending from the `standard_layout.html.twig`,
override the good block, 
and add your custom menu (copy the markup of an existing) :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block side_bar_after_nav %}
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
    <span>Custom Menu</span>
    <i class="fa pull-right fa-angle-left"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="first last">
      <a href="{{ path('custom_route') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
        Custom link
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

That's all.